# Batch file, The syntax of the command is incorrect?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Im creating a RickRoll prank for my friends i have wrote it our now but when i run it says "the syntax of the command is incorrect"

the script will run and make another bat to temp and add itself to startup it will also make a schedulede task to run it every minute.

here is the script
was

```
@echo off
goto check1

:check1
cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\
IF NOT EXIST StratUp
goto mkdir
ELSE
goto check2

:mkdir
cd %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp\
mkdir StratUp
goto check2

:check2
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\StratUp
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1
goto mkreg
ELSE
goto check

:mkreg
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run" /v StratUp /t REG_SZ /d %USERPROFILE%\appdata\local\temp\StratUp\StratUp.bat
goto check

:check
cd %USERPROFILE%\appdata\local\temp\StratUp
if NOT EXIST StratUp.bat
goto create
ELSE
goto end

:create
cd %USERPROFILE%\appdata\local\temp\StratUp
>StratUp.bat (
echo @echo off
echo start chrome.exe --new-window https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
echo exit
)
goto task

:task
schtasks /create /tn "StratUp" /tr "%USERPROFILE%\appdata\local\temp\WindowsStratUp\StratUp.bat" /sc MINUTE /d *
goto end

:end
exit
```

i also have a stopper script but i cannot test it if i dont have the original script working

here is the stopper script:

```
@echo off

goto checkdir

:checkdir
cd %USERPROFILE%\appdata\local\temp\
IF EXIST %USERPROFILE%\appdata\local\temp\StratUp
goto deldir
else
goto checkreg

:deldir
rmdir /s /q %USERPROFILE%\appdata\local\temp\StratUp
goto checkreg

:checkreg
reg query HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\StratUp
if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0
goto delreg
ELSE
goto end

:delreg
reg delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\ /v StratUp
goto deltask

:deltask
schtasks /delete /tn "StratUp"
goto end

:end
exit
```

i would appreciate help :)

Comment: You want to reduce this to a [mre].

Comment: Is your typo in `:task` (`"StratUp"`) the problem?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's intent is malicious.

Comment: Please consider reading the help for the commands you are using before posting a question.  The syntax usage for the `IF....ELSE...` command is clearly defined in the help file.

Comment: Are you aware that on most systems `%USERPROFILE%\appdata\local\temp` can be shortened to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Temp` or even more simply `%TEMP%` or `%TMP%`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not embraced the if statements with brackets. You have to do them as:

```
if exist %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\StratUp (
  goto deldir 
) else (
  goto checkreg 
)
```